# What is the word " analytica " mean?

Tags: word-usage

I saw some thinktanks use the word "analytica"  as one of the words of their name.

For example, Oxford Analytica. But I can not find the word "analytica" in my English dictionary. Is "analytica" a real word? what is the meaning?

Comment: Here's an answer from ELU: [What does “analytica” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440716/what-does-analytica-mean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Analytica* is the Latin word from which  we get the word *analytics*.

For example, *[Analytica Posteriora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_Analytics)* is the Latin title of a work by Aristotle.

Many people think Latin makes things sound more sophisticated, and in this case the word is close enough to the English one that it’s clear enough that they’re related.